# How to vlookup between 2 worksheet at google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets-formula

I want to write a code that can vlookup all data in one worksheet base data on another work sheet. The code I write:

```
   function myFunction() {
        var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //WorkSheet need to Vlookup 
        var az = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tnLn-E-03-Pt0ts6x_j-1MzWmuMJ8NyGoX810uk3a0Y");  //Worksheet 's data for vlookup
        var Sheet1 = as.getSheetByName("Sheet 1"); // Sheet need Vlookup
        var Sheet0 = az.getSheetByName("Sheet 0"); // Sheet has data for Vlookup
        var a = Sheet1.getLastRow();
        var b = Sheet0.getLastRow();
        var data = Sheet0.getRange(1,1,a,8).getValue();
        var searchkey = Sheet1.getRange(1,1,b,1).getValue();
          for (var j = 1; j<=b;j++) {
              for (var i = 1; i<=a;i++){
                 if(searchkey[j][0]==data[i][0]);
                      return Sheet1.getRange(j+1,5) = data[i][4]; 
                    //If correct "E4" at Vlookup sheet = "E4" at data sheet
                 } else { 
                 catch(e) // If wrong coutinue next For Loop
                 }
                }
               }
```

But it doesn't work. I am completely new in google app script so hope you guy give me some advice about this situation.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet with an expected output. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using tag: google-sheets-formula, I provide answer using standard one-line formula.

Let's say that source sheet (sheet1) has keys in column A and values in columns B C D

Result sheet sheet2 has keys in column A and you want all the corresponding values from columns B C D from the first sheet.

In B1 of Sheet2 you write:

```
=ifna(arrayformula(vlookup(A:A,Sheet1!A:D,{2,3,4},false)))
```

[image: =arrayformula(vlookup(A:A,sheet1!A:D,{2,3,4},false))]

ifna - leaves blank when no value is found

vlookup in arrayformula makes vlookup for whole column A, and tries to find corresponding values

{2,3,4} is a list of column indexes (from Sheet1!A:D range) to be displayed by vlookup.

false on the end means that you search for the exact key value

And this is source table in Sheet1

[image]

Is this what you were looking for?